# CloudFront Origin Path and Cache Behavior interaction

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a CloudFront distribution set up to point to an S3 bucket. My S3 bucket has a versioned path for its files (so for example, http://example.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/static/ui/v5.53.3/). I want to configure a cache behavior that only matches the `/static/ui/*` path, but I want all requests to my origin to have the path `/static/ui/v5.53.3`. I've tried to set my cache behavior's Path Pattern to `/static/ui/*` and my origin path to `/v5.53.3`, but that doesn't seem to work.

How can I configure this with CloudFront?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Origin path**
>
> If you want CloudFront to always request content from a particular directory in the origin, enter the directory path, beginning with a forward slash (/). Do not add a slash (/) at the end of the path. CloudFront appends the directory path to the origin domain name.

In your case, origin domain name is `example.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`. So the request that your origin sees is `example.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v5.53.3/*`. This is why it doesn't work.

In fact, as of May 2022, this is not possible to achieve without using Lambda@Edge. You'd have to do a custom URL rewrite in Lambda.

Comment: Hmm okay, lets say I made a request to my CloudFront that looked like this: https://mycloudfront.cloudfront.net/static/ui/index.html. When CloudFront makes a request to its origin, what does that request become when CloudFront makes the request to my origin? Does it become "http://example.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v5.53.3/index.html"? Or does it become "http://example.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v5.53.3/static/ui/index.html"?

Comment: @BrianK example.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v5.53.3/static/ui/index.html